# Is the set of $n \times n$ normal matrices a subspaces of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ over $\mathbb{C} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the set of $n \times n$ normal matrices   a  subspaces of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ over   $\mathbb{C}  $ ?

My attempts : we know  that  every  real Number is a  complex number.

if $A,B \in  M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, then

$A+B \in  M_n(\mathbb{C})$ amd $ \alpha A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$

so the set of $n \times n$ normal matrices   a  subspaces of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ over   $\mathbb{C}  $ .

Is  its  True/false

Any Hints/solution will be appreciated

Thanks u

Comment: In your "proof", you haven't used any facts about normal matrices, so it can't possibly be right. Also, note that every matric can be written as a sum of a Hermitian and a skew-Hermitian matrix.

Comment: thanks U @GerryMyerson,,let  me thinks more...

Comment: $A+B \in  M_n(\mathbb{C})$ isn't enough. You have to show (or disprove) that $A+B$ is _normal_. Same with $\alpha A$.

Comment: Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is not normal, and look at $(A+A^T)/2=\begin{pmatrix}1&1/2\\1/2&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is symmetric, and therefore normal, and to $(A-A^T)/2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1/2\\-1/2&0\end{pmatrix}$, which is antisymmetric, and therefore, normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The set $N$ of normal matrices is not a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb C)$**

If $N$ was a subspace, you would have 
$$\begin{align}(A+B)(A+B)^* &=AA^* + AB^*+BA^*+BB^* \\ &=(A+B)^*(A+B)=A^*A+A^*B+B^*A+B^*B\end{align}$$ for any $A,B$ normal matrices.

Or equivalently
$$AB^*+BA^* = A^*B+B^*A$$

For $A$ Hermitian and $B$ skew-Hermitian you get
$$A(-B)+BA = AB+(-B)A$$

I.e. $AB=BA$. So if we find an Hermitian matrix $A$ and a skew-Hermitian matrix $B$ that doesn't commute, we'll have proven that $N$ is not a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2+i\\
-(2-i) & 0\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

and you're done finding a counterexample.

Comment: thanks u @mathcounterexample